# Using the Greek letters koppa, stigma, sampi, digamma, heta, san in CM font

Tags: greek

I want to be able to use the Greek letters stigma Ϛ ϛ, koppa Ϙ ϙ Ϟ ϟ, sampi Ͳ ͳ Ϡ ϡ, digamma Ϝ ϝ Ͷ ͷ, heta Ͱ ͱ, san Ϻ ϻ, in Computer Modern font, so that they would look like the other Greek letters alpha α, beta β, etc, in their default form in LaTeX.
I found the `arevmath` package, but it is for a different font. However in this [list of symbols](https://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/arevmath-symbols.pdf) from the package, there are the symbols I'm looking for in the "Text" column, with the lowercase one not in italic (contrary to default looking greek letters in LaTeX).

Screenshot took from the link above. In red the letters I'm looking for.
[image]
Zoom of the red part :

[image]

But I didn't found any doc that tells you how to use them. The commands provided by `arevmath`, such as `\stigma`, displays like in the "Math" column.

Comment: You can find out how these characters was entered by going to the same URL but with .pdf replaced with .tex. They just load XITS Math font then enter the Unicode character into it directly.

Comment: There's also [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture). Using that method on the PDF can also reveal that that's XITS Math font.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Now I don't quite get how to create macros like `\koppa` that will display ϙ in the XITS math font.

Answer (score 1):

The New Computer Modern Unicode font includes these characters. For example, in OpTeX we can write:

```
\fontfam[newcm]

Greek letters stigma Ϛ ϛ, koppa Ϙ ϙ Ϟ ϟ, sampi Ͳ ͳ Ϡ ϡ, digamma Ϝ ϝ Ͷ ͷ, heta Ͱ ͱ, san Ϻ ϻ, in Computer Modern font.

\bye
```

and we get desired result.

Comment: How would you do this in pdfTex?

Comment: @Nolord pdfTeX does not support Unicode fonts. There is no reason to use pdfTeX in 2022, the Unicode technology is ready to use in LuaTeX roughly 15 years.

Comment: @Nolord You can always resort to `\includegraphics` then.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Comprehensive Symbols list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf):

[image]

Comment: I might sound annoying, but these doesn't look nearly as good as the one the letters above (I added pictures of what I'm looking for).

Comment: @Nolord: That's not annoying at all. I agree these don't look as good. I just posted them for reference.